# is list slicing an efficient way to write merge sort code

Tags: python

I am not a python expert so wanted to know if using list slicing in each recursive step is an efficient way to write code.

```
def mergesort(items):

    if len(items) <= 1:
        return items

    mid = len(items) // 2
    left = items[:mid]
    right = items[mid:]

    left = mergesort(left)
    right = mergesort(right)

    return merge(left, right)

def merge(left, right):

    merged = []
    left_index = 0
    right_index = 0

    while left_index < len(left) and right_index < len(right):
        if left[left_index] > right[right_index]:
            merged.append(right[right_index])
            right_index += 1
        else:
            merged.append(left[left_index])
            left_index += 1

    merged += left[left_index:]
    merged += right[right_index:]

    return merged
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, list slicing is considered good in python.

Whether it's *efficient* is another story - if you're using python in the first place, speed is probably not your goal (that's what compiled languages are for). Python generally values *clarity* and *elegance* over *speed* in coding (try opening a python console by doing `python` on the command line, and then type `import this` and read what comes up), which list slicing plays into.

But list slicing still generates a new list, and doing merge sort in-place (swapping list incides, rather than merging lists) would be more memory-efficient (and probably slightly more speed-efficient too, as a byproduct). [The wikipedia entry on MergeSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Analysis) talks about it some.

Comment: how exactly it works: slising left[left_index:] creates new list and then  merged += left[left_index:] copies it again to the end of merged list? its far from efficient for me. Worst is that it is recursive :D